# Natural Transformation and Isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

How can we see that a natural transformation $\alpha:F\to G$ between functors $F,G:C\to D$ is a natural isomorphism iff for each object $c$ in the category $C$, $\alpha_c$ is an isomorphism in $D.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that $F,G : C \to D$ are functors and $\alpha : F \to G$ is a natural transformation. You want to show that

(1) $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

(2) each $\alpha_c : F(c) \to G(c)$ is an isomorphism ($c \in C$).

are equivalent. Well, (1) => (2) is very easy (use the definitions and nothing else). For (2) => (1), show that $\alpha^{-1} : G \to F$ defined by $(\alpha^{-1})_c := (\alpha_c)^{-1}$ is a natural transformation, which is inverse to $\alpha$.

Comment: To prove this can we take opposite categories? Actually I an the bigenner in this subject, can you explain me a bit more. How do we find inverses such that diagram commutes. Thanks.

Comment: I won't explain more, since now it is your task to fill in the details. It's not much, you only have to play around with the definitions. No opposite categories.

Answer (score 5):

Often, the easiest way to show something is an isomorphism is to find its inverse.